# hid overflow of 2nd div based on height of first div (responsive)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

Maybe I'm overlooking something I don't know hehe.. But the point is this I have two columns beside each other. One, the left, should be the master of the height of the columns wrap, the right, which contains an img, should not be counted in height for the wrap's height... I can't use fixed heights, not even with Jquery or something cause the layout should change if the user drags his browser window smaller.. Thanks!

So my code is like

```
<div class="column_wrap">
 <div class="column">
  Some text
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  IMG
 </div>
</div>
```

[Example of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3yvT.jpg)

Comment: means you want to make it responsive ?

Comment: if yes you can set width of div in percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is not to contribute to the height/width it would need to be either a background image or absolutely positioned.

I've assumed that the two columns will have equal width for this scenario and I have used `flexbox` to ensure that the columns are also equal height.

**Absolute Position**

The image need an additional wrapper which is the same size as the second column like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column_wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
}
.column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.imgwrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.imgwrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_wrap">
  <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis rem, repudiandae dolores ea, exercitationem quod quos distinctio voluptate. Ratione doloribus fugiat quis eaque quia modi numquam laudantium temporibus veritatis praesentium aliquid expedita dolores, voluptates sequi, natus eum dolorum maxime. Earum iure quasi odit excepturi rerum, debitis repellat enim veniam impedit.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="imgwrap">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bVaQaO)

**Background Image**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column_wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto;
  bordeR:1px solid grey;
}

.column {
  flex:0 0 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-8.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_wrap">
  <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis rem, repudiandae dolores ea, exercitationem quod quos distinctio voluptate. Ratione doloribus fugiat quis eaque quia modi numquam laudantium temporibus veritatis praesentium aliquid expedita
    dolores, voluptates sequi, natus eum dolorum maxime. Earum iure quasi odit excepturi rerum, debitis repellat enim veniam impedit.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YyYRLY)

Comment: PERFECT AND MANY THANKS! Although in mine it only worked when I put the overflow:hidden on the column_wrap rather than on the column itself! But many thanks!! I used the position absolute variant! :)

Great!